# Why does Array.length- - not subtract 1?

Tags: javascript, arrays, decrement

When I run:
`var a = ["a", "b", "c"] console.log(a.length--)`
it prints 3, but when I run:
`var a = ["a", "b", "c"] console.log(a.length-1)`
it prints 2. Why? Isn't decrementing the same as subtracting 1?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `a--` is post decrement its first prints and then decrement but you should use here `--a` is pre-decrement  which first decrement and then prints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [decrement operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Decrement) (--) decrements (subtracts one from) its operand and returns a value.

If used postfix, with operator after operand (for example, x--), the decrement operator decrements and returns the value before decrementing.

If used prefix, with operator before operand (for example, --x), the decrement operator decrements and returns the value after decrementing.

```js
let x = 3;
const y = x--;

console.log(`x:${x}, y:${y}`);
// expected output: "x:2, y:3"

let a = 3;
const b = --a;

console.log(`a:${a}, b:${b}`);
// expected output: "a:2, b:2"
```

Answer (score 1):

It does subtract one from the length but the code posted doesn't attempt to observe the result: an array of length 2.

```js
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
console.log(a.length--)
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java script you have 2 different shortcuts to subtract an int by one. The first is the one you use here: val-- and the second is --val.
If you use any of them alone meaning you have a line that contains only val-- and thats it they do the same thing(subtract by one) but if you use them with something else(for example console.log) they have different effects.
If you use val-- the program will log the val first and then subtract by one. But if you use the --val it will first subtract by one and then log the new value.

Code that showcases this:

```
Var a = 3;
Var b = 3;

Console.log(a--);
//will print 3
Console.log(--b);
//will print 2

Console.log(a);
//prints 2
Console.log(b)
//prints 2
```

In other words what val-- does is it subtracts by one starting from the next line